# Java program crashes on eclipse with weird error

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have this java project with SWT's GUI in it.
I have been working on it for a couple of weeks now, but I ran into some problem I could not solve.

I have a MainMenu object that renders the main menu, and it has some buttons on it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainMenu menu=new MainMenu();
    menu.run();
}
```

the main menu has an inner class that extends MouseAdapter:

```
private class StartGameListener extends MouseAdapter
```

Its all purpose is to listen to the Start game button and launch up the game according to user selection, one of them offers a custom board game, where the player get to decide the initial position of the draughts on the board.
To implement that, I created an object called CustomBoard.
So, whenever the user presses the StartGame button and the "Custom Game" option is checked, it fires up the "mouseUp()" method inside the inner class StartGameListener, and instantiates a CustomBoard object and (supposed to) run it.
Problem is, whenever the control gets to the constructor line:

```
CustomBoard custom_board_menu=new CustomBoard(display, board_size);
```

I get this nasty error in the console;

```
(SWT:2806): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_closure_add_invalidate_notifier: assertion 'closure->n_inotifiers < CLOSURE_MAX_N_INOTIFIERS' failed
```

appearing over and over again in an infinite loop, and the program crushes of course.
I should (maybe) mention three things:
1. Every time different code error appears (this time it is (SWT:2806) as you can see).
2. I have **another** GUI object that runs perfectly fine from the same "mouseUp()" method. 
3. And this is the weirdest of all: When I instantiate CustomBoard object independently from the MainMenu, meaning:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomBoard cb=new CustomBoard(new Display(), 8);
    cb.run();
}
```

it works!

I tried to google it, but couldn't find any information regarding this error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a context thing... you're kicking of a UI from within another UI.  I'd check the call path to see if one of the methods you're using assumes that the whole graphics environment isn't running, yet, when in fact it already is.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @ChrisGerken. I tried to close the MainMenu shell with shell.close() before instantiating Custom board, but it didn't help. one thing did work though: when I instantiated the CustomBoard object from the MainMenu constructor, rather than from StartGameLisner's mouseUp(), it still showed this error, but at least it rendered the CustomBoard UI, and that's good progress... :-) do you have any more ideas?

Comment: This may sound silly, but try shutting Eclipse down, maybe even rebooting the system.  It's possible that a sequence of these try-and-fails has left a number of event listeners (INotifier's) still running and active.  That would explain why a simple invocation works while an invocation nested inside an event handler might not.  I saw a similar symptom with windows and window handles a long time ago and this could be the same sort of problem.  Even if this isn't the solution, you should look at having too many INotifiers from inside a event listener

Comment: OK, I'll try it. and I'll also try a few workarounds (like creating other UI object from this event handler, or trying to create another separate button for "Custom Game", since I also believe it is some kind of a system bug). I'll let you know if any of them worked. Thank you so much.